# How to use devise gem to login using mobile number and OTP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, sms, one-time-password

We have a requirement to login using multiple mechanisms and we intend to use the **devise gem**

user has the following attributes

```
 1. username
 2. email
 3. phone_number
 4. custom_id
 5. password
```

The following authentication mechanisms should be allowed

```
 1. username + password
 2. email + pasword
 3. custom_id + password
 4. phone_number + OTP (sent via SMS)
```

How do we model this using devise gem

```
 1. Does devise allow you to selectively use any option for authentication
 2. What options exist for OTP based authentication
 3. Is there any open source project which supports such customized login options
```

Comment: [driftingruby](https://www.driftingruby.com/episodes/two-factor-authentication) implements a two factor authentication using active_model_otp, rqrcode and devise gems, I hope that helps you.

Comment: @Taoufik I am not looking at MFA but authentication directly using phone number and a generated OTP

Comment: @Rpj have you found a solution for it?

Comment: nope, we didn't

Answer (score 0):

Below gem helps to you for your devise otp requirement

https://github.com/wmlele/devise-otp